# MySQL: mysql_real_escape_string in SEARCH query

Tags: mysql, sql, search, mysql-real-escape-string

How can I add `mysql_real_escape_string` to this search query?

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logs WHERE text LIKE '%$text%'");
```

`$text` comes from a POST-funktion. I have tried a lot of combinations with no success.

TRIED:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logs WHERE text LIKE '" . mysql_real_escape_string(%$text%) . "'");
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logs WHERE text LIKE 'mysql_real_escape_string(%$text%)'");
```

Comment: show us at least one variant you tried

Comment: So, it seems PHP syntax is a *terra incognita* for you.

Comment: Sorry, I have never use `mysql_real_escape_string` with %.

Comment: your problem has nothing to do neither with mysql_real_escape_string nor with %.As a matter of fact it is a trivial function call, exactly the same as you are doing with mysql_query() *or any other function*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE text LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($text)."%'")
```